# Replace OAuthPrompt card after the user has logged in

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to replace the sign in card returned from the OAuthPrompt after the user has signed in?

I tried saving the stepContext.Context.Activity.Id after calling BeginDialogAsync for the OAuthPrompt, but when I used that same id in the next waterfallstep to replace the card with a different one it throws a "Forbidden" error.

Comment: why do you want to replace the sign in card and not just continue with the dialog flow?

Comment: The login prompt card is distracting and pointless after a user has successfully logged in, and I don't want the user to continue to click it.  So if I could delete it or replace it, that would be ideal.

Comment: Our code samples are not designed to replace the sign in card as of now and gives the user an option to reuse the card. The samples which we currently have are [18](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication) and [24](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).

Comment: I know its not in the code samples; so are you saying its not possible?

Comment: @Tyler Did you find any solution for your issue?

Comment: @Krisalay No I never found a solution

Comment: @Krisalay See my answer below with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Original Answer**:

It's, as far as I know, not possible to receive a valid ReplyToId from the OauthPrompt to replace it with a message about the user being logged in successfully (or delete it). The ReplyToId is null (or string "0" on mobile).

**Update 08 feb 2022**:

Today I noticed that the ReplyToId is filled in correctly from the Microsoft Teams Desktop Client (*v1.4.00.35564*) and thus we are able to replace the sign in card on the Desktop clients!

- Note it doesn't work (*yet?*) on IOS or Android.

More refined on how to replace the OAuthPrompt Card:

After the user logged in you will receive a TokenResponse from the OAuthPrompt. In the activity there will also be a ReplyToId set, which can be used as a new reply activity's Id which then will automatically replace the OAuthPrompt Card if you use `UpdateActivityAsync`.
Make sure to check if the ReplyToId is not null or "0", because in that case it will fail (still is the case on IOS and Android) and you just send it without setting the new reply Activity's Id using `SendActivityAsync`.